# Android Share Intent - Share Button shows wrong Textview

Tags: android, button, pager

I have a problem with the share button in my android app - for example if I came from side 1 to side 2 - it shares the text of side 3 - if I came from side 3 to side 2, it shares the text of side 1. The is a problem with my share intent, but I couldnt find it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
int maxcount;


private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

TextView textview;
TextView sideview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);       
     MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
     mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider)shareItem.getActionProvider(); 
     return true;
}

private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

    }
}




public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new DemoFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("page_position", position+1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        maxcount = 10;
        return maxcount;
    }

    public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();

            int side = args.getInt("page_position");

            textview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            sideview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label2);



            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");


            switch(side) {
            case 1: textview.setText(R.string.text1);
            break;
            case 2: textview.setText(R.string.text2);
            break;
            case 3: textview.setText(R.string.text3);
            break;
            case 4: textview.setText(R.string.text4);
            break;
            case 5: textview.setText(R.string.text5);
            break;
            case 6: textview.setText(R.string.text6);
            break;
            case 7: textview.setText(R.string.text7);
            break;
            case 8: textview.setText(R.string.text8);
            break;
            case 9: textview.setText(R.string.text9);
            break;
            case 10: textview.setText(R.string.text10);
            break;
            }

            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textview.getText());
            setShareIntent(shareIntent);

            sideview.setText("" + args.getInt("page_position") + "/" + maxcount);

            return rootView;
        }

            }

}
```

}

Comment: What is the error you are getting??

Comment: There is no error but if i want to share the text in my app - the  programm shares the wrong text. The text on my second page is "text 2" but if I click to the share button, it shares the text "text 3" from my third page

Comment: position 0 should be the first side - so args.putInt("page_position", position+1) is right and works